# Regex find a substring in a string containing a pattern

Tags: regex, perl

So if the string $a = "blah bluh bu.du"
I check if the string has du in it using:

```
if( $a =~ /\.du+/)
```

Now its confirmed that the string has a ".du" in it. How can I get just the word budu now saved to a new string $b?
I am using perl
Sorry, the du was supposed to be like the a file extension

Comment: Does that really match your string?

Comment: Ummm....no, `/\du+/` checks for a digit followed by one or more `u`s.

Comment: That thing passed everything, sorry for the wrong question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the part you want to capture in parenthesis.

```
if( $a =~ /([a-zA-Z]*?du[a-zA-Z]*?)/){
    if ( defined $1 ) {
        my $word = $1;
        print "$word\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use the `\w` charclass to match letters, and to anchor at word boundaries (`\b`): `/\b(\w*du\w*)\b/`. There is also no need here for lazy quantifiers. Also, if your regex matches, `$1` *will* be defined (the shortest possible match would contain `du`). → `say $1 if $a =~ /\b(\w*du\w*)\b/`.

Comment: please see the above edits

Comment: sorry i made a stupid mistake, it worked

Comment: thanks amon i used ur answer